# Sidekiq with a tabless Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sidekiq

I have a tableless Model for a Contact page using MailForm (plataformatec). I wanted to move the mail sending to a background process using Sidekiq, but it relies on the id of given Model.

Does anyone know how I can move this email sending to a background process?

This is my model

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base 

  attribute :name,      :validate => true, :message => "aaa"
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :phone,     :validate => true
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "#{name}",
      :to => "test@test.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't persist it you need to pass all the data to Sidekiq. You could for example pass it as an Hash.

```
class ContactMailFormWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(attributes)
    contact = Contact.new attributes
    contact.deliver
  end
end
```

In your controller, model or whatever

```
ContactMailFormWorker.perform_async contact.attributes
```